# Coherent sheaf on reduced scheme is free on dense open set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

It should be well-known fact, but I couldn't find this in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry", Mumford-Oda or Ravi Vakil's Lecture notes.
Let $X$ be a reduced connected scheme and $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf on it. I want to prove that there is a dense open set $U \subset X$ such that $\mathcal F|_{U}$ is a free sheaf.

Comment: What does "descent" mean here?

Comment: @Hoot Oh, I'm sorry a lot, I meant "dense". I'll correct it.

Comment: Do you know how to do it if $X$ is integral? I believe that's in the books you mentioned.

Comment: As @Hoot has pointed out, if you add in integrality and Noetherianess, this is Grothendieck's generic freeness lemma. This goes, equivalently, by the name 'generic flatness', for obvious reasons (since your $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent). For $X$ not integral, but still Noetherian, you could just do it component by component (with the reduced structure). If $X$ is not Noetherian, then this seems annoying because the main step of devissage doesn't work in the proof.